# Not Accepting changes of already uploaded pages on server

Tags: asp.net, deployment

I found problem in uploaded project(ASP.NET) which i have done before...and after that i have made some changes latter on...but the web form and stylesheet changes are not accepting...so need solution for that...
i found little bit about it on google...that i have to give some command on cmd...but dont knw about it...

Comment: Did you deploy your changes from Visual Studio? If you did, which menu commands did you use? Or, did you just copy the revised pages to the web server?

Comment: yep i have deploy the pages(Web forms and stylsheet)in which i have made changes...and the changes whch i have made shown in localhost(visual studio) but when i have uploaded the same page on my server it doen't...

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like a browser issue, not a server issue or coding issue.  It sounds like your browser is caching the pages/stylesheets.  Did you look there yet?

Clearing your browser cache: http://kb.iu.edu/data/ahic.html

Comment: Also forcing a full download by pressing `Ctrl`+`F5` helps too.